# How to reset wireless card settings

Tags: wireless, settings

Yesterday i was playing around of the wireless settings, and set up a **tftp server**. Today, i found the wireless icon does not show up on the panel anymore.. monitor and bluetooth are still there...

I did: `ifconfig -a`, and it shows: `etho0 link encap:ethernet`, and it has:

> HWaddress inet6 addresss.
>   RXbytes 0 TX bytes: 0, but it does not even have a ip4 address, nor a mask.

The other one is:

> l0 link encap: local loopback inet addr 127.0.0.1. mask 2550 0 0

Can anyone help me how to reset the settings for my wireless connection?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

eth0 appears to be your ethernet, and it wouldn't have an ip address or mask if it wasn't connected. lo is just your loopback.

With those in mind, it appears that your wireless is not active. With your wireless working yesterday. It seems to be a module hasn't loaded. Here is what I recommend:

Try booting from a livecd, if your wireless works run this in terminal:
(you may have to add the universe repository)

> `sudo apt-get install hwinfo`

Then run the following:

> `hwinfo --network`

Find the wireless card. (wlan0)

Write down the "Driver Modules:" value. (r8192se_pci)

Boot back into Ubuntu and run this in terminal:

> `sudo modprobe <modulename>` Where  is the value from above.

(this is where I would start to find out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no soft or hard blocks on your
wireless card. On some really bad bios, if you
soft block your wireless controller, Linux maybe
unable to bring it back. It'll require a boot
into Windows to get it right. Encountered this on
my Acer Aspire One netbook.

sudo rfkill list